# Is there a date only (no time) class in Swift?

Tags: swift, date, nsdate

Is there a date-only (no time) class in Swift?  (or Foundation classes)

(as an aside if there is not but there is a well-known/popular open-source library that implements this if you could mention this)

Comment: The "date" (such as "2016-03-03") depends on your calendar and timezone, that's why you have to work with NSCalendar and NSDateComponents. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html and related docs.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve and why NSDate and friends doesn't meet your needs

Comment: If you are only concerned with time, why not use an NSTimeInterval to keep track of the number of seconds since midnight?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no date only class that's part of the Foundation framework.

This is a quick way to get a date only representation of an NSDate object:

```
let now = NSDate()

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(now)) // Mar 3, 2016
```

NSDate's always have times because a date is a single point in time. If you're so inclined you can create a date without a time component but it usually defaults to 12AM:

```
let dateString = "2016-03-03"
let dateFromStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFromStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let dateFromString = dateFromStringFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
// dateFromString shows "Mar 3, 2016, 12:00 AM"
```

For Swift 3.0+

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

// optional
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-03-03") // Mar 3, 2015 at 12:00 AM
```

Comment: if you want to mention there is currently no existing specific date only class (which seems to be the answer) I can select your response

Comment: Added that there is no foundation class that's date only.

Comment: Note that if you encode a date using a time using this approach (Foundation's `Date` is a point in time as noted above, and is fairly misleadingly named), you must to be extremely careful and consistent about the time zone and calendar that you use for any conversions forwards and backwards and for any computations. If you are not consistent, it is extremely likely that you will get inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: Use "yyyy", not "YYYY". Capital Y indicates a "week year" which I believe really only applies to the last and first weeks of the year. This isn't historically correct but just an example: if January 1 of year 2 falls on a Thursday, and you use the YYYY format for the date December 31, year 1, then "YYYY" will return "0002" because the end of that week falls within year 2. You'll incorrectly format the date as 0002-12-31.

Answer (score 21):

There isn't a date only class in `Foundation`, but you can strip the time off from a `Date` object, by using Calendar. In **Swift 4**:

```
func stripTime(from originalDate: Date) -> Date {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: originalDate)
    let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
    return date!
}
```

Or as an extension:

```
extension Date {

    func stripTime() -> Date {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
        return date!
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't strip anything really. It will just return another date with the time set to 00:00 (midnight). You can achieve the same thing by using Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)

Comment: Doesn't work, just returns an other string of the same value!

Comment: @DavidMonagle doesnt work. Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()) returns 2023-02-26 16:00:00 +0000 , not 00:00:00

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3.0

```
let date = Date()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

dateFormatter.string(from: date) // 12/15/16
```

Comment: The best solution to maintain the system's date and time format

Comment: This wouldn't necessarily work if the date you're passing in has a different time zone than the local one (e.g. from a backend).

Answer (score 5):

There is no date only (no time) type in the Swift Standard library or Foundation (as of iOS 13).

Here is a type `CalendarDate` that you can use to represent a date as year, month, day in Swift:

Also available via Swift Package Manager here: [CalendarDate](https://github.com/ralfebert/CalendarDate)

```swift
import Foundation

/**
 CalendarDate is a Swift type that represents a Date as year, month and day value.
 Includes support for formatting as a ISO 8601 string ('yyyy-mm-dd') and JSON coding.
 */
public struct CalendarDate: Equatable, Hashable {

    public let year, month, day: Int

    public static var today: CalendarDate {
        CalendarDate(date: Date())
    }

    public init(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
    }

    public init(date: Date) {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        self.year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
        self.month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
        self.day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    }

    public var date: Date {
        DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, year: self.year, month: self.month, day: self.day).date!
    }

}

extension CalendarDate: LosslessStringConvertible {

    public init?(_ description: String) {
        if let date = Self.formatter.date(from: description) {
            self.init(date: date)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    public var description: String {
        Self.formatter.string(from: self.date)
    }

    private static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension CalendarDate: Codable {

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let string = try container.decode(String.self)

        guard let value = CalendarDate(string) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(
                in: container,
                debugDescription: "Not a valid calendar date: \"\(string)\""
            )
        }

        self = value
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(self.description)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a Date object in Swift 4, like when you are trying to store a Date object in core data, you can use this method.

```
 private func getDate() -> Date {
let today = Date()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
dateFormatter .dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short

let dateAsString = dateFormatter.string(from: today)

return dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)!
}
```

based on @John R Perry's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used a solution from this thread (which worked fine) and later found out that swift provides this:

```
Locale.current.calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()) // "Sep 10, 2022 at 12:00 AM"
```

It seems to do the same as the Date extension:

```
Date().stripTime() // "Sep 10, 2022 at 12:00 AM"
```

Comment: Mine's weird. it's always Month day, year 16:00:00 +0000. I dont know where the 16 comes from. it should be 00:00:00

Comment: @chitgoks it depends on the time zone of the calendar, which is a property you can set on a Calendar object. If you get Calendar.current or Locale.current.calendar, you get the calendar in the locale that is currently set on your device. For start of day (currently, it's +4GMT here for EDT) I get 04:00:00 +0000. If I set the calendar time zone to GMT, I get 00:00:00 +0000.

Comment: it took me some time to accept that it will always be like that because of the timezone and that i have to do some formatting myself in order to get what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that string of date value specified like "YYYY-MM-DD" + NSCalendar.Identifier could represent a date.

Having this you will be able to convert this date to any other calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are some good answers already.. just wanted to pass this one in here, which prints "true", so if you use the components or just set the time to 00:00:00 is basically the same...

```
let startComp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
let first = Calendar.current.date(from: startComp)!

print(first == Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()))
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, there is no Date only type. If your goal is to display the current date which respects the locale from the user, this is the way to go:

```swift
//Returns 12/23/2022
DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date.now, dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .none)

 //Returns 23 Dec 2022
DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date.now, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .none)
```